# Two instances of same directive overwrite each other

Tags: angularjs

I am using same directive for multiple instances of a toolbar. A toolbar has a button with a toggle functionality. So, if a first click does 'add' then another click does 'remove'. Here is a simplified directive that I am using:

```
a.directive("trendChartToolbar", function ($templateRequest, $compile) {
return {
    scope: {            
    },
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        templateSRC = 'templateSRC.html';
        $templateRequest(templateSRC).then(function (html) {                
            var template = angular.element(html);
            $(elem).append(template);
            template = $compile(template)(scope);
            angular.element(elem).on('click', function (event) {
                if (scope.state === undefined)
                    scope.state = true;
                else
                    scope.state = !scope.state;
                service.someMethod(event.target.name, scope);
            });
        });                   
    }
  };
});
```

Here is the template:

```
<div>
    <img style="cursor:pointer;margin-right:10px" name="deviation"
         src="image.svg" />
</div>
```

As long as only one instance of the directive exists everything works fine. scope.state changes from true to false and back. But if another instance exists then when I click on the first instance second time the scope has state property undefined. My expectation was that as long as I am using an isolated scope it would work. Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you attaching the click handler inside the `.then` block? Why not attach it immediately?

Comment: Why are you compiling the template? It doesn't have any AngularJS directives on it.

Comment: Yes, I dont have to compile, but it doesn't affect the problem. $templateRequest returns a promise that needs to resolve before using the loaded template.

Comment: Sure seems more complex than using simple `ng-click`. Also don't need `$templateCache` if you use `templateUrl` in directive config

Comment: You are passing a scope reference to `service.someMethod`. (Not a great practice.) That method is likely modifying the contents of the scope object and is likely the source of the problem.

Comment: Let's ignore for a moment everything else except the fact that a scope of the first instance is overwritten when  the second instance is created. Why this is happening?

Comment: Create a plunker demo that reproduces the issue